# Execute sequence of sql queries in Java. Is it possible?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

When we create an SQL string dynamically in Java, is it possible to create queries to be executed one after another? 
E.g `query1;query2`?
My problem is that in a code `OpenJPA` is used to access database and in a place where an SQL `String` is being created I would like to have another SQL query run just before this one

Comment: Sounds like a transaction to me. Transactions are not part of the SQL standard, so what SQL command to use depends which type of database you're running. Another option would be to use [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API).

Comment: @JonasBystrom:Well I just want to create a temprorary table and then do a join with another table and get the result.I don' need a transaction for this I think

Comment: I couldn't get exact question. Why can't you simply create another JDBC statement with first query & execute it before your query?? Whats the exact problem?

Comment: @RaviK:Because I want to create a temporary table.Will this table exist in the second query?

Comment: Refer this link http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/samples/jdbc/s-TbTemp-java.htm

Comment: possibly use a stored procedure.

Comment: @Jim: if you just need the results you could simply do the JOIN and return the results. What would you need the resulting table for? It would help if you gave a pseudo-code example with example of what you're expecting in output.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work out of the box, but you should be able to set `allowMultiQueries` in your connection string so it does.  Temporary tables should live until the connection is closed though.  Using separate statements is preferred.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html